# Devise: Update Account without password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know that on Devise wiki pages they explain how to do it here: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

But I am new at Rails(4) and I am trying to do it for hours but I keep receiving the "password can't be blank message'. Can anyone explain how o do it for rails 4?

Updated: here is my code, I create a file in controllers called Registrations with this code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    # For Rails 3
    # account_update_params = params[:user]

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

And in my routes/config I put this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }
```

I didn't understand what else I have to do...

Comment: can you show us your controllers, what you're doing to try to do so?

Comment: Sure, I am going to update the question!

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: are you usign any custom validations for password from your model except devise::validatable module